# Find & Replace with given array elements?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Given the following:

String: `"{Dog} loves {Cat}"`,

RegExp: `{([^}]+)}`,

Array: `["Scooby Doo", "Sylvester"]`

How can I easily achieve: `"Scooby Doo loves Sylvester"`

Comment: Did you try anything in terms of code to solve this?

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'{[^{}]*}', '{}', s).format(*l)` ([demo](https://ideone.com/n1J8ib))?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew it works pretty nice. Looking for the documentation to understand this beautiful "magic" ...

Comment: Got it! All you have done is replacing matches by `{}` and then using string replacing in python 3 style. Pretty nice trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace each substring inside curly braces with a `{}` substring that acts as a placeholder when the string is passed to [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method. The list needs to be "cast" to a sequence of variables (it is called **unpacking**), thus, the prefix operator `*` is required before the list passed to `str.format`.

So, the code can look like

```
import re
s = "{Dog} loves {Cat}"
l = ["Scooby Doo", "Sylvester"]
print(re.sub(r'{[^{}]*}', '{}', s).format(*l))
# => Scooby Doo loves Sylvester
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/n1J8ib).